# How can I use fbox to enclose multiple items inside enumerate environment?

Tags: align, enumerate, fbox

I'm learning natural deduction in my logic class, and I need to write proofs according to the style shown below. I tried to use `\fbox` inside the `enumerate` environment, but it seems like that I can only box a single line. I've also tried `empheq`, but I can't seem to make nested boxes. Is there any (easy) way of achieving this style in Latex?

Thank you!

[image]
[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please show the code you used to generate the screenshot you posted.

Comment: There are packages that could help here, for example [natded](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/natded/natded.pdf) or probably closer to your example [logicproof](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/logicproof/logicproof.pdf).

Comment: @Mico I don't think my lecturer created these images with Latex. I am wondering if it is possible to achieve such a style with Latex.

Comment: Anything is possible.  But enumerate is not the way to go.  You just need a counter, a length (as in `\newlength`) and a bunch of `\parbox`es.